# Is there a definitive guide to styling forms with CSS in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer

Does someone know of a definitive guide to styling HTML forms with CSS please? I would like to get to the bottom of this once and for all because I am forever having to use CSS conditionals to sort my form fields out.

Something like a cheat sheet for forms in IE?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a full cheat sheet, but some things to know about IE6 are:

1. It does not support selectors with two classes on the same element; eg: `p span.big.red`. IE6 interprets it as `p span.red`
2. IE6 does not support :hover pseudoclass on any element except links.
3. when you make transparent PNGs work on IE6 using MS specific filters, remember that `background-position` will not work. Its just the way the filter works.

I did several projects around IE6, but unfortunately have not documented such quirks anywhere :(

Will try and add more to this answer/thread as I remember more.

Comment: thanks jrharshath. The problem I keep running into is that input fields all seem to have different margins and paddings, especially in IE7 and IE8. IE9 still renders somewhat ok but can also be the ugle step child of IE6 sometimes if it wants to be! And since I am using a reset, I would have thought that this solves the issues of padding and margins but it does not seem to be the case, so I would like to get to the bottom of it once and for all. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe form controls in IE are rendered by Windows, rather than the browser, so you’ll likely see differences between XP, Vista and 7.

The styling you get on form elements can’t be entirely described by CSS (see Eric Meyer’s blog post on the subject, [“Formal Weirdness“](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/15/formal-weirdness/)), so you’re going to have to accept some differences between browsers I’m afraid.

Roger Johansson did [some comparisons of form control renderings a few years back](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200701/styling_form_controls_with_css_revisited/), but I’m not sure anyone’s written a detailed summary of the limits of what you can do to form controls with CSS, because it’s such a huge, painful, and ever-changing subject.